# Meme Generator for Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, software-recommendation

I want free meme generator application just for fun. Is there any for Ubuntu 14.04. I have searched software center and Google but could't find it!

Comment: If application != locally installed then http://memegenerator.net

Comment: @Jan For now I am using that but i want installed, if possible. Mac have then why don't Ubuntu have

Answer (score 1):

You actually have two options,

1. **Meme Ninja**. It is a simple meme creator application and is still under development. For installing type,
   `$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nemh/gambas3
   $ sudo apt-get update
   $ sudo apt-get install gambas3-runtime
   $ wget -c https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/29344756/MemeNinja-Alpha.deb
   $ sudo dpkg -i MemeNinja-Alpha.deb
   $ sudo apt-get install -f`

To add custom meme images, paste them to: /usr/share/meme-ninja/Characters 
To add new frames, paste them to: /usr/share/meme-ninja/Frames
To add new effects, paste them to: /usr/share/meme-ninja/Text Styles

Source : [Install Meme Ninja](http://linuxg.net/how-to-install-meme-ninja-1-0-on-ubuntu-linux-mint-elementary-os-and-pear-os/)

2.**Memes!** Memes! It is an easy, simple nad fast meme generator for Ubuntu. It comes with some default templates and the ability to use custom images to create your own memes. Link : [Memes Launchpad](https://launchpad.net/memes)

Answer (score 0):

I have been using [filmora](https://filmora.wondershare.com/) through wine for most of my memes. I use it on Ubuntu 18.